# Is there a way to highlight the part of the line where an error is happening

Tags: shell-script, error-handling

I'm running this script and getting an error like this, but am having extreme difficulty detecting where exactly the error is happening. Is there an option when it points out exactly what characters are causing the error?

```
./ISCNhelperScripts/script.sh: line 34: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./ISCNhelperScripts/script.sh: line 34: `egrep -o "[)+,]dic\([1-2]?[0-9XY];[1-2]?[0-9XY]\)\([pq][0-9][0-9];[pq][0-9][0-9]\)" input | cut -c 2- |  tr '(' '\t' | tr ')' '\t' | tr ";" "\t" | awk 'BEGIN {OFS = "\t"} {print $2,$3,$4,$5}' > dicentrics'
```

Comment: The quoted command (and suggested rearrangement) both don't give an error for me.  The complete script might show the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your command so that line number in error message will give you a hint

```
egrep -o "[)+,]dic([1-2]?[0-9XY];[1-2]?[0-9XY])([pq][0-9][0-9];[pq][0-9][0-9])" input | \  
cut -c 2- | \
tr '(' '\t' | \ 
tr ')' '\t' | \  
tr ";" "\t" | \  
awk 'BEGIN {OFS = "\t"} {print $2,$3,$4,$5}' > dicentrics
```

Looks like you have problem due to unescaped braces `()` in `egrep` statement. I'd start with esaping them with backslash `\` and/or replacing double quotes `"` with single ones `'` in `egrep` statement.

Comment: Just a random comment: you do not need to escape ends of lines like `| \ `.  If the last character in line is the pipe (`|`) the line is always continued to the next one (according to POSIX).

Comment: The tip about splitting the line is valid, but the posted `grep` call has no syntax error. The shell syntax is valid and the regexp syntax is also valid.